# Independence of random variables and sums of random variables

Tags: random-variable, independence, joint-distribution, sum

I am seeking to find the joint distribution of X and Y. I have the marginal distributions of X and X+Y and they are independent.

We have that $f(X=x,Y=y)=f(X=x,X+Y=x+y)$ which is equal to $f(X=x)f(X+Y=x+y)$ due to independence. But I have my doubts about the second operation as it seems the value of X+Y directly depends on the value of X, so I am unsure we can split them up.

Many thanks

Comment: Writing $U=X+Y$ and $V=-X,$ your question asks how to find the joint distribution of $V$ and $U+V$ when $U$ and $V$ are independent. Can you answer it now?

Comment: I don’t seek the joint distribution of -X and Y though. Further I feel like my method is basically correct.

Comment: You *do* state that you want the joint distribution of $(X,Y).$ Once you have  the joint distribution of $(-X,Y),$, it's an extremely simple step to obtain what you want.

Comment: What is preventing me to state that $X=-Y$ and $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\delta(x+y)f_X(x)$?

Comment: @whuber Ah I see. So in attempting to solve it your way I encounter the same problem. $f(V=a,U+V=b)=f(V=a,U=b-a)=f(V=a)f(U=b-a)$, and I am unsure if the second operation is valid. Cheers.

Comment: @gunes This gives the same result as specified in the question, no?

Comment: What do you understand the definition of "independent" to be??

Comment: Perhaps what I am saying is wrong. One definition is that for A,B independent RV's, $f(A,B)=f(A)f(B)$, thus we can use that definition here, no?

Comment: Right.  What, then, is your question?

Comment: I’m not sure if the operation is valid in this case. I know it’s the right answer as I used a transformation and calculated the required PDF using the Jacobian, however my method stated in this question seems TOO easy...it seems I didn’t take into account the Jacobian at all, despite the 1st line definitely being correct.